# Cant save document to mongoose collection after a few validations

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to save the following object to my mongoose collection:

```
school = {
    coinPart: ['sd', 'asd'],
    crinPart: ['n', 'n'],
    ppPart: ['n', 'n'],
    quizPart: ['n', 'n'],
    submittedEvents: ['coin'],
    _id: 5f113ade6ee3cb248c6864b4,
    schoolName: 'myschool',
    teacherName: 'myteacher',
    teacherEmail: 'teacher@email.com',
    teacherPhone: '7000000000'
}
```

and this is how I am doing so :

```
console.log(school);
school.save((err, doc) => {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(err, doc);
        res.redirect(`/register/${doc._id}`);
    } else {
        if (err.name == "ValidationError") {
            handleValidationError(err, req.body);
            res.render("events/addEdit", {
                fields: req.body,
                check: allEvents,
            });
        } else if (err.name == "MongoError" && err.code == 11000) {
            res.render("events/addEdit", {
                oyehoye: "School Already Registered!",
                fields: req.body,
                check: allEvents,
            });
        } else {
            console.log("Error registering school " + err.name);
        }
    }
}
```

But after 3-4 incorrect submissions (and validating them with mongoose schema), neither do I get an error on the console, nor do I get the doc data, and localhost takes forever to load, I can't understand what I have done wrong, because when I submit the form correctly in 2-3 attempts (validating only 2-3 times), this problem isn't caused and the doc is  successfully saved.

Comment: so which if else block it is going? if it is going in final `else` where you have not sent any response it can stuck as the request does not get any response

Comment: @RohitAmbre but shouldnt it log an error on the console too?

Comment: how your payload id becomes not a string?

Comment: @SomeName yeah, it should that's why I asked in which block it is going....You can change your checks like......first `if(err)` then check what kind of error as you have already done, now create new `if(doc)` and adde success action and `else` if its here it means there's no error but doc didn't get save

Comment: I cant seem to reproduce the error right now, but can you tell me what would I do if the doc didnt get saved? is it because of a connectivity issue?

Comment: No connection will throw an error, Actually it should not reach that `else` while saving new document. You can just return response to client saying 'there some issue and try again'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to a connectivity issue, its now fixed